# Android animation animate another ImageView not which I specific

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I have a strange problem when I try to animate a ImageView which is "over" another ImageView in a RelativeLayout.

The problem is the ImageView which animate it's always which is on the "background". Here is the code: (I try to animate processing_weel but which it's animated it's processing_back!! If i change the order in the RelativeLayout (processing_weel first and then just back processing_back it works ok)

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        ... 
     />

    <TextView
       ...
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/processing_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/processing_back" />      


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/processing_weel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/processing_weel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
/**
 * Comienza las animaciones
 */
private void startAnimations(){
       ImageView processingWeel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.processing_weel);

       Animation animacion = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.processing_rotation);
       animacion.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
       animacion.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

       processingWeel.startAnimation(animacion);
}
```

processing_rotation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50.80%"
        android:pivotY="50%" 
        android:duration="1700"/>
```

Any help please?????

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Theres is a problem (BUG?) with the ImageView's ID's. There are something wrong with the '_' character...

If I use ID's processing_back and processing_weel for the ImageViews the system interprets that's the same ImageView and animate the first it found...

If I rename with back and weel works as expected.

If anybody cat try the code and verify it's a bug or not...

Thanks!